# How to express Log[b,x] in traditional format in Epilog without changing to base e

Tags: manipulate, output-formatting

I'm having difficulty understanding how to express text in `Epilog` that is dynamically updated using `Log[b, x]`.  *Mathematica* changes this to base $e$, but I would like it to be `Log[b, x]` in traditional format with base $b$, and I can't seem to make it work.  I'm guessing I need to break the $\log$ apart using boxes or something, but don't know how to make a subscript that is a dynamically updated `b` value.  Any ideas?

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[{b^x, x, Log[b, x]}, {x, -10, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-10, 10}}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
  ImageSize -> All, 
  Epilog -> {Text[b^x, {-3, 4}], Text[Log[b, x], {3, -5}]}, 
  GridLines -> {Range[-10, 10, 1], Range[-10, 10, 1]}, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Opacity[.04]], {{b, 2, "Choose a base"}, 0.01, 4}]
```

Comment: `Epilog -> {Text[Subscript[Log, b] "(x)", {3, -5}]}]`

Answer (score 3):

The code in the OP will work right off the bat if the following (sadly undocumented) setting is first executed:

```
SetSystemOptions["SimplificationOptions" ->
                 {"AutosimplifyTwoArgumentLog" -> False}]
```

After running that line, the `Manipulate[]` works as expected:

[image: now it works!]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way that let's *Mathematica* take care of the typesetting.  Use [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html) to inject the value of `b` into a held expression for the logarithm (see [`HoldForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm.html)).

```
Epilog -> {Text[b^x, {-3, 4}], Text[With[{b = b}, HoldForm@Log[b, x]], {3, -5}]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Dr. Belisarius,

```
Epilog -> {Text[Subscript[Log, b] "(x)", {3, -5}]}]
```

Comment: I think this `Text[Row[{Subscript[Log, b], "(x)"}], {3, -5}]` is preferrable.