# How to ask Mathematica to display all the logarithms (in output) in base 2?

Tags: output-formatting

How to ask *Mathematica* to display all the logarithms (in output) in base 2? Instead it always displays in base $e$.

Very often, I need to do a lot of things with mixed expressions having some $\log_2$ terms. But *Mathematica* always converts every $\log_2$ into $\ln$. So I was wondering how to ask *Mathematica* to retain the $\log_2$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As mentioned in [previous](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/101976) [answers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/107405), there is an undocumented(!) setting for this:

```
SetSystemOptions["SimplificationOptions" -> "AutosimplifyTwoArgumentLog" -> False];
```

`Log2[]` should stop expanding out after this.