# How can I write Log[a]/Log[b] in the form Log[b,a]?

Tags: pattern-matching, output-formatting

I solve the equation $2^x + 2^{x + 4} + 2^{x + 3} == 3^x + 3^{x + 4} + 3^{x + 3}$. I tried

```
Solve[2^x + 2^{x + 4} + 2^{x + 3} == 3^x + 3^{x + 4} + 3^{x + 3}, x, Reals] // FullSimplify
```

> {{x -> -(Log[109/25]/Log[3/2])}}

How can I write the answer `-(Log[109/25]/Log[3/2])` in the form `-Log[3/2,Log[109/25]`?

Comment: See and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/107405 and the `SystemOptions` setting `"AutosimplifyTwoArgumentLog"`.

Comment: @Goofy I tried that first thing. But here it does not work.  This is a reverse problem.  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4FeF.png)  How will this option otherwise help here?

Comment: @Nasser this worked for me: ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cX5Bo.png)

Comment: @Goofy sure. But you had to do the manual step `Log[a_]/Log[b_] :> Log[b, a]`  after setting this flag. I thought you meant without doing this manual step. This is same solution as Syed but instead of using `Defer` this setting is used in its place.

Comment: @Nasser Of course. How could you possibly make Mma use a particular base for `Log`? That's not what blocking autosimplification is about. `Defer` only holds up autosimplification for output purposes. It reverts to natural log when evaluated. That does not happen if autosimplification is turned off. They're different, no?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
sol = First@
   Solve[2^x + 2^{x + 4} + 2^{x + 3} == 3^x + 3^{x + 4} + 3^{x + 3}, 
    x, Reals] // FullSimplify

x /. sol /. Log[a_]/Log[b_] :> Defer[Log[b, a]]
```

> -Log[3/2, 109/25]